# SQL Server : rearrange primary key ID to start with 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CusNo] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [CusName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DateIn] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [Add1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TelNoH] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TelNoHP] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [DisSR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisSL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisCR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisCL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisAR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DisAL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadSR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadSL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadCR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadCL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadAR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ReadAL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [R] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [L] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ConSR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ConSL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ConCR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ConCL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ConAR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ConAL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Lens] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Frame] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Amount] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastUserUpdate] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [LastUpdateDate] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and I have a table `Customer` in which the `CustNo` column is the primary key. I have around 30,000 rows with manually entered `CustNo`.
I want to update all the `CustNo` to start with 1 and continuously increase by 1 until finish record.

What is the SQL query I have to use?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If your `CusNo` is a **number** - why is it stored as `nvarchar(20)` ?? First of all: it should be a **numeric** datatype (`INT`), and second of all, storing this as a 2-byte-per-character Unicode string is doubly inefficient..... and why is `DateIn` also a string??

Comment: that is another programmer design,and right now they want to upgrade the system, that why i need to re-arrange everything,inculded the database design.

Comment: @ChinYe Tell your Boss to fire 'another programmer', follow marc_c' advice on using proper data types.

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer hahaha, all right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT CusNo, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CusNo)
   FROM dbo.Customer
)
UPDATE CTE SET CusNo = RN
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50aab6/5/1) with simplified model

But i also strongly recommend to follow @marc_c advice to use the correct datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

> yup follow marcs advise. one more thing, ensure your column cusno is an Identity column so that you don't have to go through the entire process of rearranging it again.